# I have user input strings stored in a vector but when I cout the messages stored nothing get displayed. What did I do wrong?

Tags: c++, class, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Message {
public:
    Message ();
    Message (string, string, time_t);

    void changeSubject (string);
    void addMessage (string);
    void append();

    string getSender ();
    string getRecipient ();
    string getSubject ();
    string getMessage ();

    char* geTime ();
    void printEverything ();

private:
    string sender;
    string recipient;
    char* tstamp;
    string subject;
    vector <string> message;
};

void Message::addMessage (string messageo) {
    message.push_back(messageo);
}

void Message::append () {
    int n = message.size();
    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
        cout << message[x];
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{
    Message person;
    string whatyouwant;
    cin >> whatyouwant;
    while (whatyouwant != ".") {
        person.addMessage(whatyouwant);
        cin >> whatyouwant;
    }

    person.append();

    return 0;
}
```

The intention of my program is to take strings from the user and store them into a vector and later printing out the whole message by going through the entire vector and printing out the message one after another. The problem is, when I call the class function to print it, nothing gets printed. I'm not sure if it's even getting stored in the vector.

Please help, and thanks so much.

Comment: [Works for me](http://rextester.com/TXYG63669)

Comment: Please format the code to make it readable. While the compiler doesn't care about things like indentation, people do.

Comment: As for your problem, please learn how to use a debugger. It will allow you to step through the code line by line, while examining the values of variables. This will tell you if things work as expected or not.

Comment: I compiled your code and it works just fine. First of all, you have to enter text for it to print. You enter `.` when you are done entering messages and then it prints it out...

Comment: I did have to change the constructor to `Message(){}` instead of `Message();` but I'm sure you have the constructor implementation and just didnt provide it on here...

Comment: Possibly you just need `cout << endl;` at the end of your program. So far you never output a newline or flush the stream.

Comment: If you're not sure whether strings are being stored in the vector you could: (a) use a debugger, (b) print the size of the vector after storing a string in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can error check(what I do alot) is to add cout statements everywhere to check if you are actually getting anything in the vector. Try putting a for loop in your addMessage after the push_back. Something like this:

```
for(int a = 0;a < message.size();a++)
      cout << message[a] << " ";
```

This will show you what is actually in the vector after every push back. If you are getting the correct vector there, then there is something wrong with your main or append, or just how you initialized your class